# When are dependent dlls required to be present?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies

If I have an assembly, 1.dll which has has some types which depend on types in other assemblies 2.dll and 3.dll what determines if those dependent assemblies need to be present. I thought it was only if i tried to load a type from 1.dll which referenced a type from those other dlls.

for example. if i have a class `A1` which is from 1.dll and this has a method with an argument of type `A2` (from 2.dll) and I try and create an instance of `A1` then obviously I'll need 2.dll to be present in the bin to create the instance of `A1`.

If I have another type `B1` (1.dll) which depends on `A3` (3.dll) but I **don't** try and create a `B1` instance then I thought that my application should run fine even if 3.dll isn't present as I'm not trying to create any instances of things which need types which come from 3.dll.

Is this correct? What are the rules for requiring dependencies to be present?

Comment: If you do not need to call or invoke it, why would you include it in the project at all?

Comment: @jamesralston 1.dll provides types which do the bootstrapping for components in a service. Some of those components deal with routing to a particular service and so are shared between many other services that need to route to the main service. The routing classes are in 2.dll. 3.dll contains the main service's types. So the main service uses the methods in 1.dll which bootstrap the main service's types in 3.dll and the routing components in 2.dll. the other services use only the methods in 1.dll which bootstrap the routing and so only use types from 2.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies are determined at runtime, so yes, you're correct. Your application can run fine if you reference an assembly that you never use.

Excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The process of locating and binding to an assembly begins when the runtime attempts to resolve a reference to another assembly.

You can get a good sense of how the runtime locates assemblies from that article. For some proof of how it works, check out [this blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but was seeing strange behaviour that seemed at odds with that. Think we have tracked it down to an `Assembly.ExportedTypes` call that was causing all dependencies to be loaded.